# pyodbc.drivers() returns string include 'xa0'

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc, unixodbc

I use pyodbc to connect to SQL Server and installed Microsoft ODBC driver. I don't know why `\xa0` is in the driver name.

`pyodbc.drivers()` outputs driver names as `['ODBC Driver\xa017\xa0for\xa0SQL Server']` rather than `['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']`.

Therefore, I have to use 'ODBC Driver\xa017\xa0for\xa0SQL Server'. Otherwise, it won't work. Tested on Python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, they are all the same.

```
cnxn_str = ("Driver={ODBC Driver\xa017\xa0for\xa0SQL Server};"
            "Server=***;"
            "Database=***;"
            "UID=***;"
            "PWD=***;")
```

odbcinst -j

```
unixODBC 2.3.10
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/***/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
```

cat /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: The `\xa0` character is non-breaking space in iso8859-1 (ISO-Latin-1) and similar code pages. Have you checked your `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file with a hex editor to see if it's using those characters instead of a regular `\x20` (ASCII space)?

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning. You're right. There were some special characters in my `/etc/odbcinst.ini`. Not sure why they are in the file. 
Once I replaced these characters with a regular space, it displays as expected now.

I used an extension called Hex Editor in Vscode to check the file.

Comment: @Zac - What OS are you using? FWIW, I don't have that problem with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @GordThompson without any evidence whatsoever to back me up I expect copy-paste from a blog was involved. I've seen a number of pages in the past do this to prevent word-wrapping instead of using civilized things like `<pre>` blocks.

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, I'm using macOS. I guess `brew install unixodbc` wrote to `odbcinst.ini` with such special characters.